# Spring Security: Set GrantedAuthorities

Tags: spring, security, authentication

Is there anyway to set the `List<GrantedAuthority>` in the Authentication/UserDetailsImpl object? In my application, I have two layers of security, one for logging in (which uses my custom login authenticator, in the class I set the `Authentication` object using the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`) and one for a "challenge question" where the user is prompted to answer a particular question.

What I want to do is add a `GrantedAuthority` to the current `List<GrantedAuthority>`, which was created during the login process, after the user answers the challenge question.

Is this possible?

Comment: One thing to clarify on this is what class the UserDetails implementation is. Spring provides no class called UserDetailsImpl. The JdbcDaoImpl creates an instance of the User class, while the LDAP version creates an instance of LdapUserDetailsImpl. So it's really heavily dependent on what type object you're getting back whether you can change the authorities. I've never actually used one of the Spring-provided UserDetails implementation precisely because of things like immutable sets for granted authorities, which is the sort of thing that can change.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

you can do it with following code:

```
Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> oldAuthorities = (Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority>)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ANOTHER");
List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> updatedAuthorities = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
updatedAuthorities.add(authority);
updatedAuthorities.addAll(oldAuthorities);

SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal(),
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials(),
                updatedAuthorities)
);
```

Comment: The thing that sucks, is that it only works if you know the Authentication type that exists in the security context, in this case a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.

Comment: This only changes the authorities in the context, but not in the context's principal, if you try to get the authorities via SecurityContextHolder. getContext (). getAuthentication (). getPrincipal (). getAuthorities (), there won't be your updatedAuthorities, you have to set those into a new principal as well an then use it in the constructor of the authentication you're setting

Answer (score -5):

The `UserDetails.getAuthorities()` method just returns a `Collection<GrantedAuthority>` object. You can use the appropriate `Collection` method to add your new authority to that collection.

```
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
    ((UserDetails) principal).getAuthorities().add(New GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_FOO"));
}
```

Selah.

Comment: Can't add to the collection -> UnmodifiableCollection

Comment: @Slavak That would really depend on what implementation you're using for UserDetails. We don't use the User class from org.springframework.security.core.userdetails in our implementation. Obviously if you need to set or modify the authorities, using an implementation where the collection is immutable and there's no setAuthorities() method (which is not promised on the UserDetails interface) would mean that the answer to the question is just no. No, that is not possible. Otherwise, you have to provide your own implementation of UserDetails, which is what most flexible apps need to do anyway.