# possible for hibernate to auto grant privileges to other users?

Tags: hibernate

I have hibernate creating my tables and sequences automatically. Is it possible to also auto grant select privileges to another user?

Otherwise I'll have to run another script each time I auto generate my tables.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that it is the purpose of Hibernate. I would advice to apply [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) where you can even find the class [GrantedAuthority](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/GrantedAuthority.html) which shows that definitely there is some functionality to achieve your goals. I assume that this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712685/spring-security-set-grantedauthorities) might be helpful for you.

Comment: I think you mixed up what Spring Security does and the DB privilege granting.  They are usually irrelevant (unless you are doing a 2-tier application)